# Adding the value (integer) of a variable to a control name (PictureBox) in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

All my picture box controls are named the same beside the number at the end. Since I made it this way, is it possible to match an int value to the end of the PictureBox name and save copy/pasting some code?

My code:

[image: My code]

Comment: put the controls in an array (the name doesnt matter)

Comment: var pbox = this.Controls["something" + number.ToString()];

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add code in a code block in addition to the picture which shows _where_ the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

One way is to create an array and index into that instead

```
var controls = new Control[] { soldOutPB1, soldOutPB2, soldOutPB3 };

controls[index].Visible = true;
```

Another way is to use the controls collection and specify the control name as a string:

```
var control = this.Controls[$"soldOutPB1{index}"].Visible = true;
```

Comment: For the second one, I am getting an error
"Non-invocable member 'Control.Controls' cannot be used like a method."
This way seems easier if there is another way to get it to work

Comment: @hootikus, I have fixed that issue in the answer. The poster had mistakenly used parentheses to index the `Controls` collection as in VB instead of using brackets as required by C#. You really ought to have been able to fix that yourself, particularly given that the first code snippet does it correctly so you had that as an example.

Comment: @jmcilhinney well this novice knows now! Thank a terrabyte!

Comment: If you use `this.Controls.Find(ctlName, true).FirstOrDefault()` then it will be found no matter how deep it is nested...